# Alpine linux terminal mouse scroll on less command

Tags: linux, terminal, alpine-linux

Is it possible to enable mouse scroll on `less` command in Alpine Linux?

I have tried with `export LESS=-R` but that does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `less` on Alpine is provided by BusyBox (`/usr/bin/less` is symlinked to `/bin/busybox`), and provides minimal less functionality.

For mouse scroll functionality, install GNU less: `apk add less`.

See here for `less` package details:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.4/main/x86/less